# How can I programmatically determine if my app is running in the iphone simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

As the question states, I would mainly like to know whether or not my code is running in the simulator, but would also be interested in knowing the specific iphone version that is running or being simulated.

EDIT: I added the word 'programmatically' to the question name. The point of my question is to be able to dynamically include / exclude code depending on which version / simulator is running, so I'd really be looking for something like a pre-processor directive that can provide me this info.

Comment: I'm not sure a pre-processor directive is dynamic (though it might be what you were looking for anyway). The directive means that you actually knew, when you built it, where it was going to wind up running.

Comment: As I know my target is only a new iPhone or Simulator, I like `__x86_64__` ( iPhone simulator ) and `__arm64__`  ( iPhone device )

Answer (score 366, accepted):

Already asked, but with a very different title.

[What #defines are set up by Xcode when compiling for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146986/what-defines-are-setup-by-xcode-when-compiling-for-iphone)

I'll repeat my answer from there:

It's in the SDK docs under "Compiling source code conditionally"

The relevant definition is TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR, which is defined in /usr/include/TargetConditionals.h within the iOS framework. On earlier versions of the toolchain, you had to write:

```
#include "TargetConditionals.h"
```

but this is no longer necessary on the current (Xcode 6/iOS8) toolchain.

So, for example, if you want to check that you are running on device, you should do

```
#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
    // Simulator-specific code
#else
    // Device-specific code
#endif
```

depending on which is appropriate for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you this is a more specific version of your original question. If yours had come up in my original search, I wouldn't have even needed to ask.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that it doesn't show up easily in a search - I was just referencing it as a duplicate so that people could read comments in both places.

Comment: Be careful with these definitions. When you compile code with menu item 'Project > Set Active SDK > Simulator…', as TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR as TARGET_OS_IPHONE variables are both defined! So the only right way to separate logic is pointed out below by Pete (Thanks dude).

Comment: Correct, but when you compile for device, TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR is not set, so why not just switch on that? Switching on __i386__ relies on the toolchain defs, and will be invalid if compiling on a non-x86 platform (not currently possibly, of course).

Comment: Watch the #if and #ifdef difference. For me it was the cause of incorrect behavior.

Comment: as said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742525/target-os-iphone-and-applicationtests
it is not true for static libraries

Comment: Perhaps the need to include TargetConditionals has been obviated since this was written, but just wanted to note that #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR works without including TargetConditionals.h now.

Comment: Wouldn't it better to use the regular `if` instead of the pre-processor `#if` so that you have to potential to get compiler errors in both control paths? The pre-processor `#if` doesn't compile the branch that you're currently not targeting. You wouldn't want to have a false sense of accomplishment when all your code works on the simulator, but your real device branch is broken.

Comment: You may be #if-ing code that doesn't actually compile on one platform or the other, but yes, you could use if. Not sure how this helps with the false sense of achievement, you would still need to test it on both platforms!

Comment: Why the parentheses ( ) around TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR?

Comment: I needed the include in an Obj-C file for iOS 9 using Xcode 7. Hmm.

Comment: @Oren see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869481/detect-if-app-is-being-built-for-device-or-simulator-in-swift

Comment: @Dimitris It's good practice. You don't know how TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR has been defined, so !(TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR) may not be identical to !TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR

Comment: There is a better way to do this now. See my answer in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/49236898/2272561

Answer (score 106):

## Updated code:

This is purported to work officially.

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
NSString *hello = @"Hello, iPhone simulator!";
#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
NSString *hello = @"Hello, device!";
#else
NSString *hello = @"Hello, unknown target!";
#endif
```

---

## Original post *(since deprecated)*

This code will tell you if you are running in a simulator.

```
#ifdef __i386__
NSLog(@"Running in the simulator");
#else
NSLog(@"Running on a device");
#endif
```

Comment: As of iOS 8 and Xcode 6.1.1 the TARGET_OS_IPHONE is true on the simulator.

Comment: this doesn't worik anymore on newer XCode versions

Comment: Unless you are in 2016 and run a 64 bit simulator. Or in 2019 and run your code on an iPhone with Intel processor.

Answer (score 61):

Not pre-processor directive, but this was what I was looking for when i came to this question;

```
NSString *model = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"]) {
    //device is simulator
}
```

Comment: `[model compare:iPhoneSimulator] == NSOrderedSame` should be written as `[model isEqualToString:iPhoneSimulator]`

Comment: Or `[model hasSuffix:@"Simulator"]` if you only care about "simulator" in general, not **iPhone** or **iPad** in particular. This answer won't work for iPad simulator :)

Comment: Upvoted because Nuthatch's comment makes this the best answer in toto.

Comment: In iOS9, check the device `name` instead of `model`

Comment: The code won't work if a user adds `Simulator` word in his device name

Answer (score 60):

There is a better way now in Swift.

As of [Xcode 9.3](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-DontLinkElementID_24) and newer, you can use `#if targetEnvironment(simulator)` to check.

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
//Your simulator code
#endif
```

Comment: This is the only that works for me, rest of the solutions didn't work.

Answer (score 55):

The best way to do this is:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
```

and not

```
#ifdef TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
```

since its always defined: 0 or 1

Answer (score 45):

**In case of Swift we can implement following**

We can create struct which  allows you to create a structured data

```
struct Platform {
    static var isSimulator: Bool {
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
            // We're on the simulator
            return true
        #else
            // We're on a device
             return false
        #endif
    }
}
```

Then  If we wanted to Detect if app is being built for device or simulator in Swift then .

```
if Platform.isSimulator {
    // Do one thing
} else {
    // Do the other
}
```

Comment: Cleanest implementation in my opinion, and it accounts for x86_64 and i386 architectures. Helped me overcome a weird device vs. simulator bug in Core Data. You're the man!

Comment: In Playground, you will get a warning, "Code after 'return' will never be executed". So I think `#if #else #endif` will be better.

Answer (score 32):

Works for [**Swift 4.1**](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0190-target-environment-platform-condition.md) and newer and [**Xcode 9.3**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-DontLinkElementID_24) and newer

Use this code:

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
   // Simulator
#else
   // Device
#endif
```

Comment: This basically repeats [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49236898) provided 4 months earlier.

Answer (score 9):

All those answer are good, but it somehow confuses newbie like me as it does not clarify compile check and runtime check. Preprocessor are before compile time, but we should make it clearer

This blog article shows [How to detect the iPhone simulator?](http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/09/20/how-to-detect-the-iphone-simulator/) clearly

**Runtime**

First of all, let’s shortly discuss. UIDevice provides you already information about the device

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]
```

will return you “iPhone Simulator” or “iPhone” according to where the app is running.

**Compile time**

However what you want is to use compile time defines. Why? Because you compile your app strictly to be run either inside the Simulator or on the device. Apple makes a define called  `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`. So let’s look at the code :

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

NSLog(@"Running in Simulator - no app store or giro");

#endif
```

Comment: How does this improve on other answers?

Comment: @Mark It clarifies a little bit

Comment: Currently, in Xcode 7, iOS 9 Simulator `[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]` is returning `iPhone` also instead of `iPhone Simulator`. So, I think this is not the best approach.

Comment: Is there not a way to get "iPhone 14" etc..?

Answer (score 8):

**For Swift 4.2 / Xcode 10**

I created an extension on UIDevice, so I can easily ask for if the simulator is running.

```
// UIDevice+CheckSimulator.swift

import UIKit

extension UIDevice {
    
    /// Checks if the current device that runs the app is xCode's simulator
    static func isSimulator() -> Bool {        
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
            return true
        #else
            return false
        #endif
    }
}
```

In my **AppDelegate** for example I use this method to decide wether registering for remote notification is necessary, which is not possible for the simulator.

```
// CHECK FOR REAL DEVICE / OR SIMULATOR
if UIDevice.isSimulator() == false {
        
    // REGISTER FOR SILENT REMOTE NOTIFICATION
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The previous answers are a little dated. I found that all you need to do is query the `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` macro (**no need to include any other header files** [assuming you are coding for iOS]).

I attempted `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` but it returned the same value (1) when running on an actual device and simulator, that's why I recommend using `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` instead.

Comment: TARGET_OS_IPHONE is for code that might run on iOS or on MacOS X. Obviously you would want that code to behave the "iPhone" way on a simulator.

Answer (score 6):

In swift :

```
#if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64))
...            
#endif
```

From [Detect if app is being built for device or simulator in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869481/detect-if-app-is-being-built-for-device-or-simulator-in-swift)

Comment: To distinguish between mac apps: #if ( arch( i386 ) || arch( x86_64 ) ) && !os( OSX ) // we’re on a simulator running on mac, and not a mac app. (For cross platforms code included in mac targets)

Answer (score 5):

Has anyone considered the answer provided [here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-secure-storage/blob/70aa5e88691c073312e334c9963c444c3f4d86d5/secure-storage.ios.ts#L12-L24)?

I suppose the objective-c equivalent would be

```
+ (BOOL)isSimulator {
    NSOperatingSystemVersion ios9 = {9, 0, 0};
    NSProcessInfo *processInfo = [NSProcessInfo processInfo];
    if ([processInfo isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:ios9]) {
        NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *environment = [processInfo environment];
        NSString *simulator = [environment objectForKey:@"SIMULATOR_DEVICE_NAME"];
        return simulator != nil;
    } else {
        UIDevice *currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
        return ([currentDevice.model rangeOfString:@"Simulator"].location != NSNotFound);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, both `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` and `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` are always defined, and are set to 1. Pete's solution works, of course, but if you ever happen to build on something other than intel (unlikely, but who knows), here's something that's safe as long as the iphone hardware doesn't change (so your code will always work for the iphones currently out there):

```
#if defined __arm__ || defined __thumb__
#undef TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#else
#define TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR 1
#undef TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#endif
```

Put that somewhere convenient, and then pretend that the `TARGET_*` constants were defined correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To include all types of "simulators"

```
NSString *model = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
if([model rangeOfString:@"Simulator" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location !=NSNotFound)
{
    // we are running in a simulator
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with Xcode 7. If you run iOS Simulator with iOS8 (from Xcode 7) then this will work. It won't work for iOS9 where [[UIDevice currentDevice] model] returns only "iPhone" if app was launched from iOS Simulator

Comment: why not `-[NSString containsString]`?

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10), we can do this

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
  //simulator code
#else 
  #warning("Not compiling for simulator")
#endif
```

Comment: Just another copy paste

Answer (score 1):

**if nothing worked, try this**

```
public struct Platform {

    public static var isSimulator: Bool {
        return TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR != 0 // Use this line in Xcode 7 or newer
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on @Daniel Magnusson answer and comments of @Nuthatch and @n.Drake. and I write it to save some time for swift users working on iOS9 and onwards.

This is what worked for me:

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().name.hasSuffix("Simulator"){
    //Code executing on Simulator
} else{
    //Code executing on Device
}
```

Comment: The code won't work if a user adds `Simulator` word in his device name

Comment: Unfortunately with XCode 8 ```UIDevice.current.name``` reports the name of the machine the Simulator is running on (typically something like "Simon's MacBook Pro" now) so the test has become unreliable. I am still looking into a clean way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

/// Returns true if its simulator and not a device

```
public static var isSimulator: Bool {
    #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)
        return true
    #else
        return false
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple has added support for checking the app is targeted for the simulator with the following:

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
let DEVICE_IS_SIMULATOR = true
#else
let DEVICE_IS_SIMULATOR = false
#endif
```

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me best

```
NSString *name = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];


if ([name isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"]) {

}
```

Comment: On Xcode 7.3, iPhone 6 Plus Simulator returns `"iPhone"`.

Answer (score -5):

In my opinion, the answer (presented above and repeated below):

```
NSString *model = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"]) {
    //device is simulator
}
```

is the best answer because it is obviously executed at RUNTIME versus being a COMPILE DIRECTIVE.

Comment: I disagree. This code ends up in your product, whereas a compiler directive keeps the - on the device unnecessary - routine out.

Comment: The compiler directives work because the device and simulators are completely different compile targets - ie you wouldn't use the same binary on both. It *has* to be compiled to different hardware, so it makes sense in that case.

Comment: Being executed at RUNTIME makes it the _worst_ possible answer.