# TARGET_OS_IPHONE and ApplicationTests

Tags: xcode, gcc, ios, mgtwitterengine

Why doesn't this code work when compiling an ApplicationTests unit test bundle?

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else
   #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif
```

One of my dependencies has this check and compiles just fine in my main application bundles, but it tries to load `<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` when compiling my ApplicationTests bundle. It's probably just my lack of understanding of Xcode, but I get nervous when my test bundles don't build. Any suggestions?

Comment: just to add, you don't need to import foundation if you importing uikit

Comment: maybe not now, but 5 years ago? maybe.

Comment: Probably even 5 years ago as all elements in the UIKit come from NSObject => Foundation framework

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a similar problem: `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` isn't defined when building a static library.  My solution was to add "`-DTARGET_OS_IPHONE`" to the "`Other C Flags`" section of the target build options.

Comment: Yup, this ended up working.  I'm not sure how I feel about having to force this being true, but I guess it works.  Thanks.

Comment: @MattBaker - Same issue here and I agree!

Comment: That sounds like the wrong solution. You should do as antho suggested below and include TargetConditionals.h. Documented here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/15-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me in a Swift Test Target.

Answer (score 43):

You need to add

```
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
```

source: https://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-8A428/TargetConditionals.h.auto.html

Comment: When running on watchOS Scheme, I was getting all TARGET_OS_* being evaluated to 0. Using the above import solved the problem

Answer (score 20):

The simplest solution is to move the `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` statement out if the `#if` condition and replace Cocoa with AppKit like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else
   #import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#endif
```

The Foundation umbrella header imports the NSObjCRuntime header which in turn imports the TargetConditionals header.

Comment: Brilliant! This actually should be accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Both work well

- `#import "TargetConditionals.h"`
- `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

```
<Foundation/Foundation.h> 
    |
    └-#import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>
        |
        └- #include <TargetConditionals.h> 
                |
                └- defined TARGET_OS_IPHONE
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me in Xcode 12.5 is to add `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` or `TARGET_OS_IPHONE=1` to `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_NOT_USED_IN_PRECOMPS` in build settings or in an .xcconfig file.

Details:

After updating to Xcode 12.5 beta, now `carthage bootstrap` will fail when trying to build [iRate 1.12.2](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate). I looked in the carthage build log, and the error responsible for the failure is:

```
error: 'TARGET_OS_IPHONE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror,-Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_]
```

The problem for me is that iRate is no longer under development, and I'd rather not fork iRate it just to override some broken build setting.

However, there is a nifty workaround trick that I learned from the folks over at [Carthage](https://www.github.com/carthage/carthage): you can override the build settings of any project using any .xcconfig file by setting an environment variable, `XCODE_XCCONFIG_FILE=path/to/my.xcconfig` before running `xcodebuild`. Any settings in that .xcconfig file will now override the settings of whatever project you're building with `xcodebuild`.

Furthermore you can do this dynamically by a script that you call instead of calling xcodebuild, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Save this script as 'injectXcodeBuild.sh'
# Run it in place of xcodebuild (all arguments get forwarded through)
# The echo'd commands below will override any settings of the
# projects that get built by xcodebuild through this script.

set -euo pipefail

xcconfig=$(mktemp /tmp/static.xcconfig.XXXXXX)
trap 'rm -f "$xcconfig"' INT TERM HUP EXIT

echo 'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_NOT_USED_IN_PRECOMPS=TARGET_OS_IPHONE=1' >> $xcconfig

export XCODE_XCCONFIG_FILE="$xcconfig"

xcodebuild "$@"
```

Alternatively instead of `xcodebuild` this script could call `carthage` if you're needing to override some Carthage dependency's build settings. It might also work for CocoaPods `pod` command (I'm not sure).

Answer (score 0):

Note: in Swift one must use:

```
#if os(iOS)
```