# How does a program know it's launched from xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting if iOS app is run in debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744826/detecting-if-ios-app-is-run-in-debugger)

I want to add some special handling code when my program is launched from Xcode Debugger (vs. directly launched from simulator or from device). When Xcode launches a program to debug, will it set an enviroment variable?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach is to edit your debug scheme to pass a command line type argument, and detect it in main().