# Cast to different C struct unsafe pointer in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, unsafe-pointers

I want to call the Posix socket functions `socket` and `bind` from Swift. `socket` is pretty easy—it takes `Int32`s, but `bind` is causing a problem, because I have a `sockaddr_in` pointer, but it wants a `sockaddr` pointer. In C, this would be a cast, like:

```
bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sockAddress, sizeof(sockAddress))
```

Here's an attempt in Swift:

```
let sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
var sockAddress = sockaddr_in()        
bind(sock, &sockAddress, UInt32(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size))
```

The `bind` line fails to compile with: *cannot convert value of type 'sockaddr_in' to expected argument type 'sockaddr'*

How do I cast the pointer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
withUnsafePointer(to: &sockAddress) {sockaddrInPtr in
    sockaddrInPtr.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {sockaddrPtr in
        bind(sock, sockaddrPtr, UInt32(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.stride))
    }
}
```

Or someone suggests this may be better:

```
withUnsafePointer(to: &sockAddress) {sockaddrInPtr in
    let sockaddrPtr = UnsafeRawPointer(sockaddrInPtr).assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self)
    bind(sock, sockaddrPtr, UInt32(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.stride))
}
```

[This article](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/171052#171052) may be some help.

---

(UPDATE)
As described in [the link shown by Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39302927/1187415), now `MemoryLayout<T>.stride` and `MemoryLayout<T>.size` return the same value which is consistent with C's `sizeof`, where T is an imported C-struct. I'll keep my `stride` version of answer here, but that is not something "required" in this case now.

Comment: OOPs, had not seen your answer :)

Comment: [This article](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60350#171911) suggests that `UnsafeRawPointer` works in some cases. But I'm not sure which is the better in this case. Any further info are welcome.

Comment: According to https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20160815/002974.html, both are correct, with a slight favor of "withMemoryRebound", as I understand it.

Comment: @MartinR, thanks. I could not be sure, with a slight glance to the article. I'll read it again taking more time.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33177600/1187415 is a case where "size" did not work, only "stride". It *is* low-level ...

Comment: @MartinR, thanks. It seems we should always follow your third remark. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I just noticed (http://stackoverflow.com/a/39302927/1187415) that in Swift 3, size == stride for structs imported from C. So that problem does not exist anymore.

Comment: Started to write a comment regarding casting with double pointers, but I figured it would make more sense in a separate thread, if someone is interested in offering some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138411/cast-c-struct-double-pointer-to-a-swift-struct-unsafe-pointer

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3 you have to "rebind" the pointer
(compare [SE-0107 UnsafeRawPointer API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md)):

```
let sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
var sockAddress = sockaddr_in()

let result = withUnsafePointer(to: &sockAddress) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
        bind(sock, $0, socklen_t(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.stride))
    }
}
```

*Remarks:*

- The type annotations in `let sock: Int32` and `var sockAddress: sockaddr_in` are not needed.
- The `memset()` is not necessary because `sockaddr_in()` initializes
  all struct members to zero.
- <strike>The Swift equivalent of the C `sizeof` is `stride` (which includes
  a possible struct padding), not `size` (which does not include the
  struct padding).</strike> (This "problem" does not exist anymore.
  For structs imported from C, `stride` and `size` have the same value.)

Comment: If you try to use `sizeof`, Xcode recommends replacing it with `size`.

Comment: @RobN: Then file a bug report for Xcode :) In C, sizeof is the size of the struct *including* a possible padding at the end. In Swift, stride includes the struct padding, and size doesn't.

Comment: Ha. :) Well, I'll let someone else do that, since I don't know it's wrong. I did fix the question per your other remarks, to remove the noise code. Thanks!

Comment: @RobN: It makes no difference if the struct has no padding at the end. With stride you are on the safe side. Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33177600/1187415 is a (perhaps exotic) case where using size did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 obsolete the `withUnsafeBytes(UnsafePointer<sockaddr>)`, so below is what I'm doing with Swift 5:

```
        var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
    return withUnsafeBytes { (p: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) -> String? in
        let addr = p.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self)
        guard getnameinfo(addr, socklen_t(self.count), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        return String(cString: hostname)
    }
```