# Passing parameters in Metal Compute Kernel using Swift 4

Tags: image-processing, kernel, swift4, metal, metalkit

On the CPU side, I have a structure I want to pass to the compute kernel:

```
  private struct BoundingBoxParameters {
    var x: Float = 0
    var y: Float = 0
    var width: Float = 0
    var height: Float = 0
    var levelOfDetail: Float = 1.0
    var dummy: Float = 1.0  // Needed for success
  }
```

Before running the kernel, I pass in the data to the MTLComputeCommandEncoder:

Option 1 (directly):

```
commandEncoder!.setBytes(&params, length: MemoryLayout<BoundingBoxParameters>.size, index: 0)
```

Option 2 (indirectly via MTLBuffer):

```
boundingBoxBuffer.contents().copyBytes(from: &params, count: MemoryLayout<BoundingBoxParameters>.size)
commandEncoder!.setBuffer(boundingBoxBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
```

Either option works fine if the 'dummy' variable exists in the structure, but fails if the 'dummy' variable does not exists. The code fails in the call to:

```
commandEncoder!.dispatchThreadgroups(threadGroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadGroupCount)
```

With the error:

```
validateComputeFunctionArguments:820: failed assertion `Compute Function(resizeImage): argument params[0] from buffer(0) with offset(0) and length(20) has space for 20 bytes, but argument has a length(24).'
```

On the Metal Kernel Side, here's the relevant code snippets:

```
struct BoundingBoxParameters {
  float2 topLeft;
  float2 size;
  float levelOfDetail;
};

kernel void resizeImage(constant BoundingBoxParameters *params [[buffer(0)]],
                        texture2d<half, access::sample> sourceTexture [[texture(0)]],
                        texture2d<half, access::write> destTexture [[texture(1)]],
                        sampler samp [[sampler(0)]],
                        uint2 gridPosition [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
  float2 destSize = float2(destTexture.get_width(0), destTexture.get_height(0));
  float2 sourceCoords = float2(gridPosition) / destSize;
  sourceCoords *= params->size;
  sourceCoords += params->topLeft;
  float lod = params->levelOfDetail;
  half4 color = sourceTexture.sample(samp, sourceCoords, level(lod));
  destTexture.write(color, gridPosition);
}
```

I also get a similar issue when trying to pass in a 3x3 matrix to another compute kernel. It complains that 36 bytes are provided but expecting 48.

Anyone got any ideas on the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First-off, I want to point out that you should not be using [`size`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout/2432227-size) when you need to get an actual length of a Swift type laid out in memory. You should use [`stride`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout/2429192-stride) for that. According to Swift's [Type Layout](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst#fragile-struct-and-tuple-layout):

> The final size and alignment are the size and alignment of the aggregate. The **stride** of the type is the **final size** rounded up to alignment.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39302927/6192057) goes into detail about memory layout in Swift if you want to get a better understanding of the topic.

---

The problem is that your `Metal struct` that uses `float2` and a `Swift struct` that replaces it with two separate `Float` fields have different memory layouts.

Size (stride in case of Swift) of the struct needs to be a multiple of the largest alignment of any struct member. The largest alignment in your `Metal struct` is *8 bytes* (alignment of `float2`) so there's a padding at the tail of struct after the `float` value.

```
struct BoundingBoxParameters {
    float2 topLeft; // 8 bytes
    float2 size; // 8 bytes
    float levelOfDetail; // 4 bytes
    // 4 bytes of padding so that size of struct is multiple 
    // of the largest alignment (which is 8 bytes)

}; // 24 bytes in total
```

So your `Metal struct` does in fact end up taking up *24 bytes* as the error suggests.

At the same time, your `Swift struct`, having the largest alignment of *4 bytes*, only needs *20 bytes*.

```
private struct BoundingBoxParameters {
    var x: Float = 0 // 4 bytes
    var y: Float = 0 // 4 bytes
    var width: Float = 0 // 4 bytes
    var height: Float = 0 // 4 bytes
    var levelOfDetail: Float = 1.0 // 4 bytes
    // no need for any padding 

} // 20 bytes in total
```

That's why they end up incompatible with each other and `dummy` field compensating *4 missing bytes* to `Swift struct`.

To resolve this I suggest you use `float2` from `simd` in Swift instead of `Float`s:

```
import simd 

private struct BoundingBoxParameters {
    var topLeft = float2(x: 0, y: 0)
    var size = float2(x: 0, y: 0)
    var levelOfDetail: Float = 1.0 
}
```

**Don't forget** to use `MemoryLayout<BoundingBoxParameters>.stride` (*24 bytes*) to get the length instead of `size` (*20 bytes*).

---

Same goes for the 3x3 matrix case: Metal's `float3x3` has size of *48 bytes* and alignment of *16 bytes*. As I assume, you've created a `Swift struct` with 9 `Float`s which would have stride/size of *36 bytes* and alignment of *4 bytes*. Hence, the mis-alignment. Use `matrix_float3x3` from `simd`.

In general, for any cases when you use vectors or matrices in Metal you should use corresponding `simd` types in Swift.

Comment: Thank you for the super helpful answer. That solved the issue.

Comment: I wish I'd found your simd suggestion a month ago. Very well explained, and helpful. Thanks! :)