# Cast C struct double pointer to a Swift struct unsafe pointer

Tags: c, swift

I need to do the following C casting in Swift (4):

```
struct A ** castme = input
struct B * tothis = (struct B *)castme
```

In Swift, `castme` type is `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<A>?>!`

I assume I am trying to cast to `UnsafeMutablePointer<B>!` ?

Also, would it be correct to say that I could also cast `*(castme)` to a `(struct B)` directly? If yes, would it make casting easier by casting from `UnsafeMutablePointer<A>?` to `B` ?

I saw this thread but wasn't able to get what I needed from it:
[Cast to different C struct unsafe pointer in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184544/cast-to-different-c-struct-unsafe-pointer-in-swift)

Comment: Hmmm, casting a _pointer to a pointer_ to a `struct` pointer is unsafe in C too as posted here.  Need to see more of code for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think about that in terms of what's happening in C. When I do a cast of pointers in C, the data that represents the pointer type will now be treated as a pointer of a different type. The value of the pointer doesn't change, just how you treat it.

Swift doesn't like to do this kind of thing and doesn't encourage you to do it because while cheap, it's a fundamentally unsafe thing to do and can lead to corrupting data, jumping into space, bus errors, etc.

That doesn't mean that swift doesn't have the ability to do this. The link that you point to uses `withUnsafePointerTo` which tries to limit the scope of the use of the pointer. In your case, you probably want to look at `unsafeBitCast` (documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641250-unsafebitcast)) which mimics the C pointer cast (it's not strictly the same as C casting in general, but for pointers it is).

```
let a:UnsafeMutablePointer<SomeType> = fetchASomeTypePointer()
let b = unsafeBitCast(a, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<SomeOtherType>.self)
```

This makes the data representing the pointer to `SomeType` now become a pointer to `SomeOtherType`.

Like I said before, this is a dangerous thing to do especially if you don't fully understand what you're doing.