# Detecting if iOS app is run in debugger in a release build

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am working on an SDK that will be used in iOS apps. When I release the SDK, I'd like collect data on whether the applications that are using my SDK are running under the debugger when they are running.

[This Apple developer blog post](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1361/_index.html) shows how to detect this, but it explicitly calls out that you should only use the code in the debug build of your program. Because I'll be building a release build of the SDK, it seems unsafe to include.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if Swift app is being run from Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177182/detect-if-swift-app-is-being-run-from-xcode)

Answer (score 2):

This block will work and is production safe.

```
#if DEBUG
    //Do something on debug
#else
    // Do something on prod
#endif
```

Comment: Sure, but I'm talking about an SDK, not an app. So I can't enforce that the apps that use the SDK will write ifdef's like this.

Comment: @jparismorgan if it’s an iOS SDK then you definitely can.