# Notification when Xcode deploy will terminate the app?

Tags: ios, xcode

When an app is attached to the Xcode debugger, none of the usual lifecycle methods (`applicationWillResignActive:`, `applicationWillTerminate:`, etc.) or notifications (`UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification`, etc) are triggered.

Is there any way for the app to know it's about to be stopped or re-deployed? Perhaps by trapping a signal?

Comment: There is a way to determine [whether you're running in the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4746378/290913), which I use to autosave my current state much more frequently. However it'd be nice to get notified directly so I'm not wasting CPU and disk resources.

Comment: If you want a normal notification, you can press the home button to terminate the app/resign active...  The intent of Xcode debugging is for developing an app, maybe if you explain your use case it will make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  For all intents and purposes, the STOP button in Xcode immediately terminates the application.  There isn't a way to catch this.

Answer (score 0):

**applicationWillResignActive** and **applicationDidEnterBackground** and their counterparts do get triggered when you press the home button on the device or simulator (or when you come back).  I don't think you can catch the ones related to termination.