# Can iOS ARM code ever be run in a simulator?

Tags: ios, runtime, simulator, compile-time

If I distribute an iOS framework library that [detects a simulator at compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5122286/79202), the part of the fat binary that’s compiled for the simulator will always work in the simulator, and the code outside the `#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` macro will always work on a device. So is it really ever necessary to [detect a simulator at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19908567/79202)?

In other words, can the ARM device parts of the fat binary every find themselves running on a simulator?

Comment: "So is it really ever necessary to detect a simulator at run-time?" and "can the ARM device parts of the fat binary every find themselves running on a simulator?" are totally, completely different questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the ARM code can never run in the simulator. The simulator can - by definition - only execute native - i.e. Intel - code. Otherwise, it would be called *emulator*.

(Android has a device emulator as opposed to iOS' simulator.)