# XCode - Check with constant if my program is running in simulator o device

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I programmatically determine if my app is running in the iphone simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458304/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-app-is-running-in-the-iphone-simulato)

How I can check in XCode 4 with constant if my program is running in simulator o device?
Something like this:

```
#ifdef RUNING_ON_DEVICE
#else
#endif
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458304/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-app-is-running-in-the-iphone-simulato

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of options

Preprocessor macro:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
//is sim
#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
//is real device
#else
//unknown target
#endif
```

Or, if you'd rather do it in some arbitrary method:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"]) {
    //device is simulator
}
```