# Any way to Allow Location Simulation on simulator only?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Location Simulation is cool on simulator, but interferes with my normal use of devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional if:

1. `#include "TargetConditionals.h"`
2. Include the simulator only code this way:

   > ```
   > #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
   > //code for simulator only
   > #endif
   > ```

*Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/458388/312312

Comment: I don't get it. I'm talking about Xcode's Location Simulation. I don't think it is something you can control in code.