# iOS: How to check what simulator my App is running on?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I POSTED MY ANSWER FOR THIS.

## Please check.

I am able to check programatically if I am running my app on Simulator or not.
But I want to know what simulator I am running like...
1. iPhone Retina (3.5 inch)   OR
2. iPhone Retina (4 inch 64 bit)   OR
...
x. iPad Retina
etc.

**Please help.**

```
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *machine = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
free(machine);

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5S";
...
...
```

> ```
> if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
> if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
> ```

Comment: Hi Guys, this is solved. Actually I was finding it by device class. Thanks for your replies anyways. Thanks guys!

Comment: How can I move this question to solved state?

Comment: post your answer here and check it as accepted so others can use it in future. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maul and Divya... This is how I check...

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

//Check the scale (I use it to see the pixel density
CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

NSInteger w=(unsigned)screenBounds.size.width * screenScale;
NSInteger h=(unsigned)screenBounds.size.height * screenScale;

// I don't want to check the device orientation.
//So, make always height greater than width.
(w>h)?(w=(w+h)-(h=w)):1;
```

Now, you can include the checks if height (variable h) is 960 or 1136 => iPhone
Or, if height is 2048 => iPad

In my code... just to mimic that I am running the app on the physical iPad/iPhone... I return the string...

```
iPad 4
iPhone 5
```

etc.

LET ME KNOW WHAT YOU THINK, tell me if I can improve the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 +(NSString *)yesButWhichDeviceIsIt   
 {  
 BOOL hasRetina = NO;  
 if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)])  
 {  
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];   
    if (scale > 1.0) 
    {
        hasRetina = YES;
    }
    }
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
    {
    if (hasRetina)
    {
        return @"iPad retina";
    } 
    else
    {
        return @"iPad";
    }
    }
    else
    {
    if (hasRetina) {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568){
            return @"iPhone5"; // simulator 4 inch
        }
        else
        {
            return @"iPhone4s"; simulator 3.5 inch
        }
    } else {
        return @"iPhone"; simulator(normal)
    }
}
```

}

This will be easy to test the device types both on simulator and device. Unless you need which type of phone it is (GSM/CDMA) For checking device type we does not need to check which type of carrier the device have.

Comment: read question carefully before going to answer. don't mislead visitors.

Comment: @Mani actually this work perfect ... i used this for developing 40 app's . i edited my answer check it

Answer (score -2):

Use following code like below, and its working for me .

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
NSString *deviceType  = @"iPhone simulator!";
#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
NSString *deviceType = @" Device";
#else
NSString *deviceType = @"Other";
#endif
```

Here is reference : [How can I programmatically determine if my app is running in the iphone simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458304/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-app-is-running-in-the-iphone-simulato?rq=1)