# Unable to determine if the Xamarin Forms application is running in the Simulator or on the Device

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to determine if the app is running in the simulator or on the hardware (Apple iPhone) device.

Various answers are all suggesting that I do the following:

```
bool isSimulator = MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.Arch ==
    MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Arch.SIMULATOR;
```

which I've added to my iOS app `AppDelegate.cs` file. But it does compile - I'm missing a namespace or assembly.

Here's a pic of the FULL method (with the colour coding showing it cannot find the static property):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Using Clause:

```
using ObjCRuntime;
```

#### Code:

```
bool isSimulator = Runtime.Arch == Arch.SIMULATOR;
```

FYI: The `MonoTouch` namespace is deprecated (~2012) and has been broken up into multiple namespaces within the "Xamarin.iOS" product.

Comment: You don't actually need the using ObjCRuntime if you are specifying it in the code. Correct on the MonoTouch namespace not been needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach that uses the `UIDevice.CurrentDevice` information:

```
public static class IosHelper
{
    public static bool IsSimulator {
        get {
            return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Model.EndsWith("Simulator") || UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Name.EndsWith("Simulator");
        }
    }
}
```

Derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3511144/1099111).