# Is there a way to tell if my code is running in Apple Watch Simulator or on a real watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

There are somethings that don't work correctly in the simulator. I'd like exclude them during my development when I'm on the simulator.  Is there any way programmatically I can tell if the code is running in the simulator or not.

Comment: try answers here. They are for iPhone but see if you can extend them for Apple Watch. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458304/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-app-is-running-in-the-iphone-simulato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this in watchKit.

```
    NSString *modelNameStr = [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] name];
    NSLog(@"modelNameStr: %@ ...", modelNameStr);

    if ([modelNameStr isEqualToString:@"MacBookPro2012"]) {
        //device is simulator
    }
    else
    {
        //its a real watch?
    }

2016-01-25 22:32:12.540 Watch Extension[4275:131894] awakeWithContext ...
2016-01-25 22:32:12.541 Watch Extension[4275:131894] willActivate ...
2016-01-25 22:32:12.595 Watch Extension[4275:131894] modelNameStr: MacBookPro2012 ...
```