# How can I make a iPhone app compatible to 2.2.1 and 3.1 SDK?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-sdk-2.2.1

I have made some apps in 2.2.1 now when I run the same app in 3.1 it gives errors.
Changing the codes is a solution I am not looking for.
I am looking for some pre-processor directives that can make my app compatible to both SDKs.
Something like  `#ifdef`.

Thank You All.

Comment: What's broken?  You might have to change the codes...  But you could change the codes in a way that maintains compatibility with 2.2.1.  Those darn codes.

Comment: Hi Nick,
Can provide me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to [How to target a specific iPhone version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820142/how-to-target-a-specific-iphone-version/823287)

You can use this #define to change what you build for each SDK...

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > __IPHONE_2_2
// iPhone 3.0 code here
#endif
And do this at run-time to run code for 3.0 and above:

float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (version >= 3.0){
    // iPhone 3.0 code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks micmoo,I am going to try it it out.