# Compatibility of 2.2.1 with 3.0

Tags: iphone

I have few application developed in 2.2.1.When i am running this with 3.0 few errors are displayed.Now i want to write some code around this error to support the version which is selected.
Had anybody developed an application which run on both version of iphone.Small snippet will be appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198129/how-can-i-make-a-iphone-app-compatible-to-2-2-1-and-3-1-sdk) on Stack Overflow...