# How do you detect multiple iphone OS, equal to and greater than, using macros?

Tags: iphone, ipad, macros, detect, operating-system

I am trying to execute different things depending on what os the users iPhone is using.

Currently I have the below, which says - "if the device is 3.1, post this message"

```
    #ifdef __IPHONE_3_1
    NSLog(@"this device is 3.1");
    #endif
```

But, How can I get it to say - "If the device is 3.1 **or higher**, post this message" ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to target a specific iPhone version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820142/how-to-target-a-specific-iphone-version)

Comment: +1. It sounds like you want the app to work on versions lower than 3.1. Preprocessor macros don't do that; see the second half of the accepted answer there.

Comment: Yes, thank you both. Chris you were right. Macros were the wrong for what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Well this seems to do it.

```
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_3_2
    NSLog(@"this device less than 3.2");
    #endif
```

I don't know why though because, to me, it reads - " if the OS version is greater than or equal to 3.2"
But, it returns - "if the iPhone OS is below 3.2"

Can anyone explain what this actually means?

Comment: Well __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_REQUIRED seems weird to me; maybe you should use __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED instead.