# Video capture code does not work on iphone 4

Tags: iphone

I have captured video in iPhone 3GS using the UiImagePickerController, but the same app does not engage the Video camera on iPhone 4,it is also working fine on iPhone 3GS (OS 4).

Following is the code i used to engage the video camera.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];   
[imagePicker release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify your 
`UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice` 
to either 
`UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear` or `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront` 
on the iPhone 4

Also, set

`UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode` 
to 
`UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo`

[iPhone UIImageController Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraDevice)

Comment: How should i detect which is the current OS version on the device.

Comment: Ok this is what i got:

  
 NSString *systemVersion=[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
  

 if([systemVersion floatValue]>4.0)
{
    imagePicker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode=UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
       imagePicker.videoQuality=UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
  
}

Comment: alternatively, you can check if the device is available using isCameraDeviceAvailable (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImagePickerController/isCameraDeviceAvailable:)

please use this solution for system version:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820142/how-to-target-a-specific-iphone-version