# How to scroll to UITextField placed into a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, keyboard, uitextview

I've got an UIScrollView with an UIImageView at the top and an UITableView.

inside every cell of the UITableView I've placed a UITextField

I would like to know how I can automatically scroll to the UITextField selected so that it doesn't go under the keyboard

I've already looked at this [Get UITableView to scroll to the selected UITextField and Avoid Being Hidden by Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265559/get-uitableview-to-scroll-to-the-selected-uitextfield-and-avoid-being-hidden-by-k) but it doesn't works very well for my situation..

could you help me?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Check out Matt Gallagher's fantastic [Sliding UITextFields around to avoid the keyboard](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html).  It ought to be just what you need. You can modify it to only scroll a specific element, or just leave it as is to scroll the whole superview.

Comment: I still have a little problem... as I said before I've got an UIscrollview with an image and a table inside it...
this is what it happens with that code..http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/263/schermata20110607a19485.png/
 could you help me? thank you