# UITableViewController not automatically scrolling with Keyboard once owning TableView is pushed on the UIViewController's subview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have been playing with `UITableView` for some time and upon hitting the keyboard and scrolling issue, I decided to solve it by using the `UITableViewController` and take advantage of the automatically scrolling when the keyboard shows up. Unfortunately, this does not occur for me and I can not figure out why, I have tried many things and give up to ask the community.

Here is what I have so far:

1. A regular `UIViewController` handling a `UIView` (*MyView.xib*) (this is
   also the root view)
2. A regular `UITableViewController` handling a
   `UITableView` in a separate `XIB` file (MyTable.xib)
3. A regular `UITableViewCell` has been dragged into (MyTable.xib) and resides side by side with the `UITableView`. This `UITableViewCell` has no custom class. Also there is an outlet connected to `UITableViewController` class.
4. A regular `UITextField` sits under the `UITableViewCell`
5. I have associated the file's owner identity in MyTable.xib to the `UITableViewController` class
6. I have connected the delegate and datasource of the `UITableView` to the file's owner

This is how it looks in IB in MyTable.xib

- `UITableView`
- `UITableViewCell`

  - `UITextField`

So when I generate my table rows in the UITableViewController, I dequeue the first 5 rows to be regular cells and for the last row I return my outlet "myCell" (UITableViewCell). This is the one that has the UITextField.

```cpp
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    if (indexPath.row == 5) return myCell;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test"];

    return cell;
}
```

Finally, in my `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, I create an instance of the `UITableViewController` and display it. It successfully shows the 5 rows and my custom one at the bottom. All in the main view, but ...

```cpp
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

mtc = [[MortgageTableController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTable" bundle:nil];
mtc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 375);
[self.view addSubview:mtc.view];
}
```

The problem I'm having is, if I click on the `UITextField`, I don't see the table automatically being scrolled in view. I thought this was one of the advantages of using `UITableViewController` or I maybe I'm doing something wrong here.

I also tried selecting and/or scrolling the table to the row but with no luck.

Comment: Asked and answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265559/get-uitableview-to-scroll-to-the-selected-uitextfield-and-avoid-being-hidden-by

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to call super viewWillAppear to make the scrolling automatically.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // your code
}
```

EDIT: Jul 19, the precondition for this to work is that your controller is a subclass of UITableViewController

Comment: Thank you so much! I wondered why it worked so easily on one view but not the other! Everywhere else I looked got into some tedious code to re-align the whole view for the keyboard...

Comment: Perfect answer! So simple.

Comment: awesome..it just saved my day

Answer (score 1):

As you are embedding the tableView in a superView, you don't get the typical behavior of a table view controller. What happens with a talble view controller when it is controlling a full screen tableView (for example pushed on a navigation controller), is the table view is resized when keyboard appears.

As what you have mainly is a view controller, you have to do the work: add your view controller or your table view controller as keyboard notification observer and scroll your table view to the position you need.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That's a very surprising design. What you are saying is that once I add a TableView to the subview of a UIViewController (the parent), even though all it's functionality of the view is controller by UITableViewController (the child), I do not get the child's interaction behavior ? So pushing a tableView on a Navigation Controller is different than pushing it on the parent UIViewController ?

I have tried your suggestion but the scrolling appears to be a littler choppier than I liked, so I wanted to try the build in function of the UITableViewController.

Comment: I had this problem too, this helped a lot: 
'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: Is it true that adding a tableview controller won't autoscroll when you put it on a uiviewcontroller?. Do you have any reference which states that?.For me the auto scrolling works in my sample project but not in my real project, Curious to know the nuances.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue but I was using a tableviewcontroller so I should have gotten the tableview offsetting behavior for free. The issue turned out to be that I was calling `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];`. I believe this caused the tableviewcontroller to not receive this notification (I'm thinking maybe an object can only registered 1 method per notif). Changing the above to `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];` solved my issue.