# UITableView doesn't scroll when keyboard appears

Tags: uitableview, ios6, keyboard, uitextfield

I have attempted Apple's example here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

However, it doesn't seem to work so I'm clearly missing something along the way, just can't figure out what.

I have a ViewController.h containing:

```
@interface PreferencesViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, defaultLocationChoice, UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *defaultLocation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *defaultTestType;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <defaultLocationChoice> locationDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *locationnameTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *locationaddressTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *activeField;
```

There are all Synthesized in the .m file.

I have the Apple code has follows in ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSUserDefaults *sharedPref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    defaultLocation =[sharedPref stringForKey:@"defaultLocation"];
    defaultTestType =[sharedPref stringForKey:@"defaultTestType"];

    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];


    self.navigationItem.title = @"Preferences";

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications

{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification

{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible

    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.

    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {

        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);

        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    } 
}



// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification

{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

{
    activeField = textField;
}



- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField

{
    activeField = nil;
}
```

The Cells containing the TextFields are dealt with in CellForRowAtIndexPath as below (full code not shown):

```
  case 2:
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:

                    prefCell.textLabel.text = @"";
                    prefCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                    prefCell.highlighted = NO;
                    locationnameTextField.frame = CGRectMake(5, 12, 300, 30);
                    locationnameTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
                    locationnameTextField.placeholder = @"Enter location name i.e. New York, NY";
                    locationnameTextField.delegate = self;
                    locationnameTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
                    [prefCell.contentView addSubview:locationnameTextField];

                    break;
                case 1:
                    prefCell.textLabel.text = @"";
                    prefCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

                    locationaddressTextField.frame = CGRectMake(5, 12, 300, 30);
                     locationaddressTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
                    locationaddressTextField.placeholder = @"Enter location address i.e. mcs.newyork.com";
                    locationaddressTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
                    locationaddressTextField.delegate = self;
                    locationaddressTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

                    [prefCell.contentView addSubview:locationaddressTextField];

                    break;
            }
```

On running the app the keyboard pops up and nothing happens.

Apples example is for a View so the only code I changed above was `self.view.frame` to `self.tableView.frame` to no effect.

I added the ScrollView as an addition as I didn't have one. My other ViewControllers with embedded TableView don't require a ScrollView to scroll.

The hierarchy is as follows:

[image]

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to do as following:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
 [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: this removes the keyboard if the TextField is selected and I try scrolling, which isn't what I need. I require the active TextField to move above the keyboard when it appears.

Answer (score 0):

I was scratching my head with the same problem when I noticed the superview of textfield. If I'm right, you have the textfield inside a cell of tableview.

Now, in your `keyboardWasShown:` method, you are checking whether active text field is hidden under the keyboard like this:

```
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

The `if` condition will never be true in your case. Since the superview of active text field is a cell, the `activeField.frame.origin` will return a point in reference to a UITableViewCell, not in reference to your UIView.

Hence, what you need to do is check if the **cell containing** the active text field is hidden under the keyboard, something like this:

```
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, cellForActiveField.frame.origin) ) {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, cellForActiveField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

To find the cell containing active text field, you need to set the `tag` property of textfield in `tableView:cellForIndexPath:` method and then check for the tag in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method.

For more details, refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265559/get-uitableview-to-scroll-to-the-selected-uitextfield-and-avoid-being-hidden-by) as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since I found it, I use [TPKeyboardAvoiding](http://icodetricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/uitextfields-and-keyboard-issues/)

It is working great, and is very easy to setup:

1. Add a UIScrollView into your view controller's xib
2. Set the scroll view's class to TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView (still in the xib, via
   the identity inspector)
3. Place all your controls within that scrollview