# Is there a simple replacement for MonoTouch.UIKit.UIKeyboard.BoundsFromNotification?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, deprecated, uikeyboard

```
MonoTouch.UIKit.UIKeyboard.BoundsFromNotification(MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNotificaton)]
```

was [deprecated in iOS 3.2](http://api.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIKeyboard.BoundsFromNotification%28MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNotification%29). Is there a simple replacement method/snippet I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New methods were added in iOS 3.2 to replace the deprecated one. Look at [UIKeyboard](http://api.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M:MonoTouch.UIKit.UIKeyboard.BoundsFromNotification%28MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNotification%29) documentation for `FrameBeginFromNotification` and `FrameEndsFromNotification`.

There's a stackoverflow question that shows how to update your code at [How to get UIKeyboard size with Apple iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546571/how-to-get-uikeyboard-size-with-apple-iphone-sdk) it's in Objective C but should be easy to convert into C#