# Sizing tableView XIB to the size of on-screen custom keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib, custom-keyboard

I am trying to create a custom keyboard. This keyboard will have a UITableView in it. When I load the keyboard, the bottom of the UITableView runs of the screen.

I am using this code to size the UITableView.

```
 _tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Any ideas how I size it to be the same height and width of the available keyboard space?

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546571/how-to-get-uikeyboard-size-with-apple-iphone-sdk

Comment: Not what I am after as my post is for a systemwide custom keyboard.