# iOS foreign language keyboard heights?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I'm trying to debug keyboard height issues in the iOS simulator, I need several keyboards that are different heights. There are about 40 keyboards that are built-in and can be added via Settings.

Which of the built-in keyboards have different heights than the default English keyboard?

Note: I'm not looking for a 3rd party keyboard since I want to minimize the amount of variables I need to deal with. Also, I want to be able to do this kind of testing at anytime without the need to install another app.

Comment: Do you have evidence that system keyboards have different heights ? I don't think they do.

Comment: @deadbeef I've found one so far: Chinese handwriting.

Comment: Well That's good to know. But that means I can't answer you question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## iPhone 6 (9.0)

### Portrait:

- **English** (predictive text disabled): 216
- **English** (predictive text minimized): 225
- **Chinese (Simplified) - Handwriting**: 252
- **Emoji**: 258
- **English** (predictive text maximized): 258
- **Chinese (Simplified) - Pinyin - 10 Key**: 283.5

### Landscape:

- **Chinese (Simplified) - Pinyin - 10 Key**: 162
- **English** (predictive text disabled): 162
- **English** (predictive text minimized): 171
- **Emoji**: 194
- **English** (predictive text maximized): 194
- **Chinese (Simplified) - Handwriting**: 198

---

## iPad Air (9.0)

### Portrait:

- **English** ([shortcut bar only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319697/view-aligned-to-top-of-keyboard-appears-in-wrong-place-in-ios-9-shortcut-bar-onl)): 55
- **English** (without shortcut bar): 265
- **Emoji**: 303
- **English** (with shortcut bar): 313
- **Chinese (Simplified) - Handwriting** (without shortcut bar): 406
- **Chinese (Simplified) - Handwriting** (with shortcut bar): 461

### Landscape:

- **English** (without shortcut bar): 353
- **Emoji**: 391
- **English** (with shortcut bar): 398
- **Chinese (Simplified) - Handwriting** (without shortcut bar): 406
- **Chinese (Simplified) - Handwriting** (with shortcut bar): 461

---

Note: all values are ordered by size then name.

Note: *shortcut bar* refers to the iOS 9 [Shortcut Bar](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios9-preview/) and/or iOS 8's [QuickType](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/quicktype/) bar which is enabled/disabled by choosing the *Predictive* and *Shortcuts* options.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably solve the issue you want by grabbing the keyboard height at runtime instead. This will work if apple changes keyboard heights in the future.

You can do that by registering for UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification and then get the height from there. Reference: [How to get UIKeyboard size with Apple iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546571/how-to-get-uikeyboard-size-with-apple-iphone-sdk). Be sure to look at the second answer that references Chinese.

Comment: I'm trying to debug an issue with a method such as that (for example), hence I would need to do the opposite: find a keyboard of a known size, and ensure that the above method sets the height correctly.