# How to get custom's keyboard height in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I am trying to adjust my scroll view to prevent keyboard from covering `UITextField`. I've managed to do it based on answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present) and Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7).

Using

```
CGRect keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
```

returns correct CGRect for a default keyboard, however it doesn't calculate it properly when user has third-party keyboard installed. For example SwiftKey keyboard.

Any ideas as how to calculate keyboards frame/height even if custom keyboard is being used?

Comment: Please show your real code (i.e. what you're really doing).

Comment: @matt Does my code matter here? Everything works without issues with the exception of custom keyboard. Unless UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey should return correct height for a custom keyboard as well.

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546571/how-to-get-uikeyboard-size-with-apple-iphone-sdk ?

Comment: @Starlord Yes, as you can see in my initial post, this is exactly what I'm using.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?  I get a lot of bouncing until the real value is given which happens on the 2 call for custom keyboards