# NSAutolayoutConstraint - Apply constant before multiplier

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

Today the `multiplier` property is read-only. In order to change it, you have to remove the constraint and create a new one.

```
let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: constraint.firstItem,
    attribute: constraint.firstAttribute,
    relatedBy: constraint.relation,
    toItem: constraint.secondItem,
    attribute: constraint.secondAttribute,
    multiplier: newMultiplier,
    constant: constraint.constant
)
```

In this example, first the multiplier will be applied and then the constant. For example:

Imagine it's a width constraint to the superview.

This means we'll have `view.width = superview.width * multiplier - 2`.
(which also means that a `multiplier = 0` will break).

What I need is `view.width = (superview.width - 2) * multiplier`. How do I create such constraint?

I also don't want to do something like:

```
let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: constraint.firstItem,
    attribute: constraint.firstAttribute,
    relatedBy: constraint.relation,
    toItem: constraint.secondItem,
    attribute: constraint.secondAttribute,
    multiplier: newMultiplier,
    constant: constant * newMultiplier
)
```

Because I end up losing the `constraint.constant` that comes from the storyboard.

Comment: `view.width = (superview.width - 2) * multiplier` this one also could crash

Comment: FWIW you're writing your constraints using the old harder way. Use anchors instead. See [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/125718/coding-auto-layout) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074872/programatic-constraints-not-obeyed/44078258#44078258)

Comment: In this case I don't have (or want to) a pointer to the view, so only to the constraint. So how would I use anchor in this case?

Comment: To get the result you want, you *probably* will need to embed your view inside another view. Set "OuterView" width constraint to superview.width + constant of  `-2`, and set "InnerView" width constraint to *its* superview.width * multiplier.

Comment: Thank you @DonMag I thought of that, but feels like a hack to add another view just for that.

Comment: It depends a lot on what all you're trying to do. If you browse through some of Apple's auto-layout examples, it's not unusual to see embedded views. For that matter, it wouldn't surprise me to find out that "under the hood" `UIStackView` uses similar techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to change a multiplier value? Change constant value instead..

declare inside the class

```
var yourViewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

Instantiate this constraint

```
yourViewWidthConstraint = yourView.widthAnchor.constraint(self.view.widthAnchor)
yourViewWidthConstraint?.isActive = true
```

Now, change `yourViewWidthConstraint.constant` anywhere..

Comment: Because I want the width of one view to be proportional to the width of another. How can I do that with constant since I don't have the correct frame at the time I set the constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your superView is main screen.

```
newConstraint.constant = (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width - 2) * your_multiplier
```

Comment: It isn't the main screen and the bounds property is not correct at the time I need to update the constraint.

Comment: That's why i used 'let's say'
However it does not matter. Knowing the width of the view is easy depends on how you have created it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try next:

```
class MyConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    fileprivate var storyboardConstant: CGFloat!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        storyboardConstant = constant
    }

    func copy(with newMultiplier: CGFloat) -> MyConstraint? {
        guard let viewWidth = constraint.secondItem?.bounds?.width,
              let _ = storyboardConstant else {
            return nil
        }
        let newConstraint = MyConstraint(
            item: constraint.firstItem,
            attribute: constraint.firstAttribute,
            relatedBy: constraint.relation,
            toItem: constraint.secondItem,
            attribute: constraint.secondAttribute,
            multiplier: newMultiplier,
            constant: storyboardConstant * newMultiplier
        )
        return newConstraint
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In these images, Purple is the "SuperView" ... Orange is the "OuterView" ... Blue is the "InnerView"

For your use, Purple and Orange will likely have `.clear` background color.

The Width Constraint of "SuperView" controls the width of its two subviews - in this example, Orange will be `-2` of Purple's width, and Blue will be 90% of Orange's width (0.9 multiplier).

---

"SuperView" is simply set to a Width and Height, and centered in its parent view.

[image]

---

"OuterView" is set Equal Width to its superview (Purple / "SuperView"), with a Constant of `-2` (no multiplier)

[image]

---

"InnerView" is set Equal Width to *its* superview (Orange / "OuterView"), with desired Multiplier - I used 0.9 in this example.

[image]