# How to AddConstraint to a button relative to parent view's margin so that it appears 30 from top margin and 30 from right margin

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

This is the code I'm trying out:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var btnInfo: UIButton!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view,
                                             attribute: .topMargin,
                                             relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: btnInfo,
                                             attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant: 20))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view,
                                             attribute: .rightMargin,
                                             relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: btnInfo,
                                             attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant: 30))
}
```

Trying to add `.topMargin` and `.rightMargin` constraints to get the `btnInfo` to appear 30 points from top and 30 from right margin. Please help.

Comment: Use anchors! It will make your life easier. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074872/programatic-constraints-not-obeyed/44078258#44078258)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If interface builder is an option, interface builder works great for this type of functionality.  Select the object you are wanting to add your margins to and set constant margins on the top and the right.

Here is a screen capture.
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Your answer helped me and solved my problem.

Comment: Always glad to help!