# Adjust the height of UINavigationBar according to Wrapped title height?

Tags: iphone

I m in a problem that I have added a label as subview in Navigation bar and due to limited height of navigation bar it is not showing another line of wrapped title text.So I want to adjust height of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have faced the same problem and I got the answer.Please try this link:
```

[How to set the height of UINavigationBar according to the length of the text in TitleView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172235/how-to-set-the-height-of-uinavigationbar-according-to-the-length-of-the-text-in/10172442#10172442)

May it help u...!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ios 5.0 then

you can take a background Image a bit bigger and navigationbar will be set according to the Image.

It mught help you have a try :).

[setting an Image on navigationbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894594/could-not-set-image-on-navigation-bar-only-in-ios-5-0)