# Sprite Kit, Suppressing quality for slower iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, performance, sprite-kit

I am finding that the game I am making performs amazing on the newer iPhones (5,5s), but older ones like the 4 and 4s are less awesome (especially the 4). What are your thoughts about detecting the type of phone the user has, and providing them a lower quality experience to improve performance? Also, if you do this, what are some best practices you have come up with?

Comment: [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820142/how-to-target-a-specific-iphone-version).  I'm surprised you didn't find anything with a simple google search

Comment: It's not the iOS version I am checking for, it's the kind of phone. And the question is not about how to check it, I'm asking for opinions if it's something that is good to do for performance considerations.

Answer (score 3):

Try detecting the iphone model like so...

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

    if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone 4"]) {
        //Then, based on the model type, limit the frame rate.
        skView.frameInterval = 2;
        //setting the frame interval to 2 clips the fps to 30.
    }
```

Comment: Are your SKTextures taking up heavy memory?

Comment: No, it seems to be mostly my physics simulations that are causing performance issues, some of them are just aesthetic and can be ditched for performance.

Comment: You think halving the frame rate might improve performance? that's interesting, thanks, I'll give it a try