# No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm attempting to run the Xcode project that was recently completed and I have one error to sort. Any help is greatly appreciated....

There is a Semantic Issue that appears before the error - The warning is as follows :

> Undeclared selector 'boundingRectWithSize:options:atrributes:context'

The ARC Semantic Issue error is as follows :

> No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:'

The code is below...

```
// Since sizeWithFont() method has been depreciated, boundingRectWithSize() method has been used for iOS 7.

if ([NSString instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)]) {
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
        CGRect requiredLabelRect = [self.textLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:contentViewSize
                                                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.textLabel.font,
                                                                               NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
}
                                                                 context:nil];
```

Comment: What is your project's Base SDK and Deployment Target?

Comment: You can silence the warning (if that's what you want) by saying `[(id)(self.textLabel.text) bounding...`

Comment: Could it be that you're accidentally compiling this code with an OS X (AppKit) SDK? The API you're using is UIKit specific.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your code like this (using #if #endif directives): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820142/how-to-target-a-specific-iphone-version and don;t let this code compilable for SDK other than ios 7.

Comment: ARGGGH!!! Updated Xcode to latest version and the error went away!