# Macro definition in cross-platform

Tags: c++, iphone, c, android, macos

When development various platforms(Android,iPhone,Mac,Windows and so on), it is necessary diverged processing(#ifdef/#endif) by depends on an platform definition.
But, I don't know original definition in Mac/iPhone/Android.

Windows : WIN32 (Visual C++)

Mac : __MAC_NA(?)  (XCode)

iPhone/iPad/iPod : __IPHONE_NA(?) (XCode)

Android : ?? (AndroidNDK)

By what definition should I divide?

Comment: Windows uses `_WIN32`, not `WIN32`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

For iPhone, I believe the define is TARGET_OS_IPHONE and for Android it's ANDROID.  I'm not too familiar with Apple-specific stuff, but after poking around I found a great list for tons of OS defines [here](http://predef.sourceforge.net/preos.html).  There's another answer here on SO that has a method for pulling the defines out, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146986/what-defines-are-setup-by-xcode-when-compiling-for-iphone)

Comment: That's good point.
TARGET_OS_IPHONE and TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR defined was exist.

>>Android it's ANDROID
Oh, it could divide by ANDROID defined. Thanks.

Comment: It defined it as follows. 
[ANDROID -> Android]
[TARGET_OS_IPHONE or TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR -> iPhone/iPad/iPodTouch]
[WIN32 -> Windows]
[When TARGET_OS_IPHONE and TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR is not define and __APPLE__ is defined -> Mac]
[Otherwise -> Unix or Linux]

Answer (score 4):

You could always make some up for your projects, thereby freeing yourself from compiler/platform specific `defines`.

- Android: `#define PLATFORM_ANDROID`
- Iphone:  `#define PLATFORM_IPHONE`
- etc.

And have all builds include a configuration file that defines one of these macros in a given project and that should work across the board. If you're using Visual Studio, you can just define these in the Project Settings without even needing a configuration file.

Comment: This is really the only safe, clean way to do it. I've seen the alternative in several programs (GNU screen is the worst I can think of) and it becomes a nightmare. Not to mention, if your code is testing any macro definition that begins with _ which isn't explicitly defined in the C standard, it has unspecified behavior.

Aside from this, you really should avoid testing for platforms and assuming presence/absence of features based on the platform. Platforms change a lot over time. It's much better to test for specific features you want to use and have something like `#ifdef HAVE_FOO`.

Comment: Uh, huh. I see.
When development in linux OS like ubuntu, the way seems to be good. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Android NDK uses definition ANDROID.