# Create a parallel build for Simulation only

Tags: xcode

**Scenario:** I'm using a static library w/in an iOS project that doesn't work within the simulator (i386 env).

**Goal:**
I would like to be able to isolate the library-dependent code and build a) only for the simulator so I can continue with the rest of the project functioning; and b) the regular build for the device.

**This is what I've done:**

1) I created another target (via duplicate), and removed the static library and dependent links & builds.

2) Commented out the reference code in the source.

**Question:** Is it possible to conditionally compile a line of code per scenario or must I always have to comment-out the sensitive code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What #defines are set up by Xcode when compiling for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146986/what-defines-are-set-up-by-xcode-when-compiling-for-iphone)